# How to sort a mysql table in a specific way

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the following table as a result of a query:

```
    SELECT f.id, f.parent_id, f.name, f.fullpath, 
    FROM folders f
    WHERE fullpath LIKE CONCAT("%", 'fs-3', "%") 
    ORDER BY fullpath ASC, name ASC;
```

```
id      parent_id       name        fullpath
-----------------------------------------------------------------
fs-3    null            root        fs-3
fs-d    fs-3            test        fs-3/fs-d
fs-5    fs-d            test        fs-3/fs-d/fs-5
fs-g    fs-3            test3       fs-3/fs-g
fs-2    fs-g            test        fs-3/fs-g/fs-2
fs-s    fs-2            test        fs-3/fs-g/fs-2/fs-s
fs-y    fs-3            test2       fs-3/fs-y
fs-4    fs-y            test        fs-3/fs-y/fs-4
```

The table is sorted by

```
ORDER BY fullpath ASC, name ASC
```

The desired outcome is that `name column` gets sorted in a manner where `test3` comes after `test2` while keeping the `fullpath` sorting. But I don't know how to achieve this?

```
id      parent_id       name        fullpath
-----------------------------------------------------------------
fs-3    null            root        fs-3
fs-d    fs-3            test        fs-3/fs-d
fs-5    fs-d            test        fs-3/fs-d/fs-5
fs-y    fs-3            test2       fs-3/fs-y
fs-4    fs-y            test        fs-3/fs-y/fs-4
fs-g    fs-3            test3       fs-3/fs-g
fs-2    fs-g            test        fs-3/fs-g/fs-2
fs-s    fs-2            test        fs-3/fs-g/fs-2/fs-s
```

Comment: Create a stored function that resolves the name of each segment of the `fullpath`, e.g. `fs-3/fs-y/fs-4` becomes `root/test2/test`, then sort by that value: `ORDER BY ResolvePathName(fullpath)`

Comment: Good idea Andreas, but I want to refrain from stored functions in this case.

Comment: `CONCAT("%", 'fs-3', "%")` evaluates to `'%fs-3%'`. What's the point?

Comment: Query comes from a stored procedure. Is normally a variable. Simplified the query for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you [want to refrain from stored functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248607/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-specific-way/60248977#comment106569290_60248607), you need to rebuild the path using names instead of ids, using a MySQL 8.0 recursive query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT f.id, f.parent_id, f.name, f.fullpath
       , CAST(f.name AS CHAR(50)) AS namepath
    FROM folders f
   WHERE f.id = 'fs-3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.id, f.parent_id, f.name, f.fullpath
       , CONCAT(cte.namepath, '/', f.name) AS namepath
    FROM cte
    JOIN folders f ON f.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT id, parent_id, name, fullpath
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY namepath
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9JrZf73aXApR5dJZELS32R/0) for demo.

Answer (score 1):

If you have MySql 8.0 or greater than:

```
WITH RECURSIVE folders_path (id, name, path) AS
(
  SELECT id, name, name as path
    FROM folders
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.id, f.name, CONCAT(fp.path, '/', f.name)
    FROM folders_path fp JOIN folders AS f
      ON fp.id = f.parent_id
)
SELECT f.id, f.parent_id, f.name, fp.path 
    FROM folders f JOIN folders_path fp on f.id = fp.id
    WHERE fullpath LIKE CONCAT("%", 'fs-3', "%")
    ORDER BY fp.path;
```

[See DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qnjP5kHQRHEGCgdRYxnnH/0)

Note: In the above DB Fiddle I did not bother to add the `fullpath` column since as the sample data added already satisfied the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It would seem that I came late to the party.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional sorting:

```
select f.* 
from folders f
where fullpath like concat("%", 'fs-3', "%")
order by
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from folders  
      where name = 'test2'
      and f.fullpath like concat(fullpath, '%')
    ) then 1
    when exists (
      select 1 from folders  
      where name = 'test3'
      and f.fullpath like concat(fullpath, '%')
    ) then 2
  end,
  f.fullpath,
  f.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qu8EUZntaaRg2peWBzQTmp/0).
Results:

```
| id   | parent_id | name  | fullpath            |
| ---- | --------- | ----- | ------------------- |
| fs-3 | null      | root  | fs-3                |
| fs-d | fs-3      | test  | fs-3/fs-d           |
| fs-5 | fs-d      | test  | fs-3/fs-d/fs-5      |
| fs-y | fs-3      | test2 | fs-3/fs-y           |
| fs-4 | fs-y      | test  | fs-3/fs-y/fs-4      |
| fs-g | fs-3      | test3 | fs-3/fs-g           |
| fs-2 | fs-g      | test  | fs-3/fs-g/fs-2      |
| fs-s | fs-2      | test  | fs-3/fs-g/fs-2/fs-s |
```